# Generate same random sample each time in loop using sample_frac

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I generate same random sample each time in loop using `sample_frac`

```
library(dplyr)

tbl = tibble(val = 1:50)

for (i in 1:3)
{
   tbl_sample = tbl %>% sample_frac(0.1)
   print(tbl_sample)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `list` and then assign it to the `list` element by looping over the sequence - `print` only prints the output to the console

```
n <- 3
lst1 <- vector('list', n)
for(i in seq_len(n)) {
    lst1[[i]] <- tbl %>%
       sample_frac(0.1)
}
```

If we want to get 5 random indices

```
for(i in seq_len(n)) {
    lst1[[i]] <- tbl %>%
     mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
     slice_sample(prop = 0.1)
}
```

---

In addition this can be automatically done with `replicate`

```
lst1 <- replicate(n, tbl %>% 
                   sample_frac(0.1), simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to (step - 1) generate 5 random indices (ex - 1, 4, 19, 34, 48) before the loop begins and then (step - 2) filter tibble based on those indices each time loop

Comment: @SiD in that case, you can create a sequence column with `row_number()` before doing the `slice_sample` or `sample_frac` (updated the post

Answer (score 1):

We can use `purrr`, and loop through `1:3` with the same expression as the `.fn` argument:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map(1:3, ~{
        tbl_sample = tbl %>% sample_frac(0.1)
        head(tbl_sample)
})

[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 1
    val
  <int>
1     1
2    20
3    35
4    32
5    19

[[2]]
# A tibble: 5 x 1
    val
  <int>
1    45
2    24
3    42
4    46
5    10

[[3]]
# A tibble: 5 x 1
    val
  <int>
1    35
2    23
3    28
4    49
5    43
```

You may want every sample in a single column in a dataframe. For that we may use `imap_dfc`:

```
imap_dfc(1:3, ~{
        tbl %>% sample_frac(0.1) %>% head %>% set_names(paste0('sample_', .y))
})

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  sample_1 sample_2 sample_3
     <int>    <int>    <int>
1       49       17        8
2       29        9        6
3       25       35       50
4        9        4       44
5       34       45        3
>
```